# How to use stopPropogation() for live events?

Tags: jquery

HTML CODE:

```
  <li id="list_id">List_text<img src='image.jpg' id="img_id"></li>
```

jQuery Function:

```
$("#list_id").live('click' , function(){
 alert('List is clicked');
});

$("#img_id").live('click' , function(){
 alert('Image is clicked');
});
```

Once i click image its parent li function is also triggered. Give me a solution to solve this. I need to trigger img event only when i click img element and need to trigger li event when i click li element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) here to be safe, since the event handler is at the same level ([`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event handlers live on `document` by default), like this:

```
$("#list_id").live('click' , function(){
 alert('List is clicked');
});

$("#img_id").live('click' , function(e){
 e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 alert('Image is clicked');
});
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/MNAch/).

---

Note, this doesn't do the job if you're on jQuery < 1.4.3, for that you also need to check if it's stopped using [`e.isImmediatePropagationStopped()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.isImmediatePropagationStopped/), like this:

```
$("#list_id").live('click' , function(e){
 if(e.isImmediatePropagationStopped()) return;
 alert('List is clicked');
});

$("#img_id").live('click' , function(e){
 e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 alert('Image is clicked');
});
```

Comment: It wont works for me. .live function wont allows propogation events.

Comment: @Mohan - Which version of jQuery are you on?  If it's < 1.4.3 you'll need an additional check, I added the info above.

Comment: @Mohan - I don't follow your comment...but the second solution in the answer applies for your jQuery 1.4.2, or upgrade to 1.4.4 and use the first.

Comment: Thank u. It works for me. If i upgrade my jquery to 1.4.2 to 1.4.4 means any problem comes for me or not.

Comment: @Mohan - shouldn't have any issues, it has more fixes (like propagation!), but as always just click around and make sure any plugins you have are working as expected, just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#img_id").live('click' , function(){
 alert('Image is clicked');
return false;
});
```